# PHPUnit doesn't load some of the tests

Tags: unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I have a tests folder in one of my modules, with 3 subfolders:

```
Model
Helper
Integration
```

running

```
phpunit --group My_Module
```

executes only the tests in Model and Helper directories, with the Integration folder left untouched. Test files reside directly in the folder in all of the cases, so I'm not sure what's causing the problem.
Here's my phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- initial phpunit configuration file, that you can modify for your project needs -->
<phpunit cacheTokens="true"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         strict="false"
         verbose="false"
         bootstrap="app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/bootstrap.php">
    <listeners>
        <listener file="app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Listener.php" class="EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Listener" />
    </listeners>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MyApp">
            <directory suffix=".php">app/code/local/*/*/Test/*/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Magento Test Suite">
            <file>app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit/Test/Suite.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <!-- Exclude Magento Core files from code coverage -->
            <directory suffix=".php">app/code/core</directory>
            <!-- Exclude EcomDev_PHPUnit classes from code coverage -->
            <directory suffix=".php">app/code/community/EcomDev/PHPUnit</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/EcomDev/Utils</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/EcomDev/PHPUnit</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Spyc</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/vfsStream</directory>
            <!-- Exclude Mage.php file from code coverage -->
            <file>app/Mage.php</file>
            <!-- Exclude template files -->
            <directory suffix=".phtml">app/design</directory>
            <!-- Exclude Varien & Zend libraries -->
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Varien</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">lib/Zend</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <!-- Uncomment this line if you want to have coverage report generated every test run
        <log type="coverage-html" target="var/phpunit/coverage" charset="UTF-8"
              yui="true" highlight="false"
              lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="var/phpunit/coverage.xml"/>
        -->
        <log type="junit" target="../build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

The version of PHPunit I'm running on ubuntu VM is 3.7.28. How can I get all of the tests to run? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add your tests in "Integration" to My_Module group?

Comment: Yes I did. What's weird as well, is that Tests in Model and Helper have the group tag as well, so not sure what is different between the two folders.

Comment: Does it stay like that if you rename "Integration" to "Controller" or some other name that fits the Magento-Structure?

Answer (score 2):

Try to call

```
phpunit --list-groups
```

This show you list of available test groups. Do you see My_Module in list?
1) Yes - issue in tests folders/structure.
2) No - issue in xml configuration.

Comment: I can see the module and it runs the tests in folders mentioned above, but not in the Integration folder.

Comment: A bit stupid question, but: do you set group annotation in tests?      /**
 * @group Integration
 */
public function testSomeIntegrationFunctionality() { ... }  http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group

Comment: Is it required by EcomDev to set the @group annotations? I thought you can spare those by editing the modules `etc/config.xml` file.